# Networking between Virtual Machines in a Virtual Network

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have set up file sharing and SQL Server instance connectivity between two VMs (`testPC01`, `testPC02`) in a Virtual Network on Azure.

The problem is that I cannot connect between these VMs by name (`testPC01`, `testPC02`), but only by their IP addresses (`10.0.0.4`, `10.0.0.5`).  I cant even ping the names.

I haven't fiddled with any network settings.  These are fresh VMs.

How can I resolve by name and not by IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see similar thread: [Azure VMs Virtual Network inter-communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995734/azure-vms-virtual-network-inter-communication)

you will have to configure your own DNS for name resolution.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  So is there specific software that I should install onto a separate 'DNS' VM to handle name resolution?

Comment: yes. if that's just two machines and you don't want the overhead of a DNS server, you can just manually put entries in each machine's hosts file.

Comment: What about setting up a static IP?  [This post says otherwise.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546857/need-to-setup-dns-server-on-azure-vm)

Comment: Oh, static IPs are only impossible for non-VNet VMs.