# Simple internal communication between Azure VMs on the same Virtual Network

Tags: azure

I have created 2 VMs in the same Virtual Network within the same Cloud Service. They do not have public endpoints. I would like to have the VMs be able to recognize each other as if they are on a local network. For example, I'd like to be able to reference them by machine names using \\ syntax, e.g. on VM1, I'd like to be able to access \\VM2_host_name\shared_folder. Can someone please provide me the steps to configure my VMs to enable this scenario.

Notes: I tried referencing them by their internal IP addresses, and also enabled ICMP traffic in the Windows Firewall. I even entirely turned off the firewalls for both machines just to test. No luck. I can't ping these machines either by host name or IP address from the other machine even without firewall. I have also reviewed similar sounding questions such as ([Azure VMs Virtual Network inter-communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995734/azure-vms-virtual-network-inter-communication)) but to no avail.

More Information:

From VM_A (internal IP 10.0.0.5), I'm trying to communicate with VM_B (internal IP 10.0.0.4). Both VMs belong to the same cloud service "MyCloudServiceName". For this test, I also turned off their firewalls just reduce the variables at play.

```
C:\Users\Matt>NSLookup VM_B
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  168.XX.XXX.XX

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    VM_B.MyCloudServiceName.hX.internal.cloudapp.net
Address:  10.0.0.4


C:\Users\Matt>ping VM_B

Pinging VM_B.MyCloudServiceName.hX.internal.cloudapp.net [10.0.0.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.5: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.5: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.5: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.5: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

So what I can tell is that the DNS resolution is working. But the machines are still isolated from each other even within the same cloud service.

Note that my actual scenario is I have an ASP.NET Web API self hosted on a service running on one machine which I'd like to be able to access from the other in the same cloud service internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar issue and it was due to the Checksum Offload of the Network Adapters.
Thanks to Microsoft Azure Support for helping us diagnose the issue.

The simple fix is to run this on every machine then do a quick reboot:

`Disable-NetAdapterChecksumOffload * -TcpIPv4`

Here is an article describing the problem in more details:
http://systemscentre.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/problems-clustering-virtual-machines-on.html

Answer (score 0):

PING may not work as its often disabled in network environments. So I would suggest an NSLookup to verify it is able to resolve the location of the other server.

If both VMs are already in the same cloud service, virtual network should not be necessary as Azure provides basic DNS resolution within that cloud service boundary. By doing a NSLookup -all on each server, you should be able to identify the names they are currently using.

Once you've verified that they can resolve each other, you shouldn't have any other issues getting them to address each other providing you're not using an unsupported protocol (such as UDP multi-cast).

Comment: I tried NSLookup just now and it seems the DNS resolution is working properly. They can resolve each other. Now it seems the problem is isolated to the actual communication. I edited my question above with some notes on more details I couldn't fit in this comment.

Comment: 1) is the ping service running on VM_B?
2) what port are you trying to connect to on VM_B and how are you trying to connect?

Comment: Yes, I verified pinging as a service is running on VM_B by RDP'ing into VM_B, launch cmd then ping localhost which works fine. For the ping test, I am just pinging the hostname so no port is specified. I am using command line.

Comment: lets try another approach. ensure IIS is running on both machines with the default web site. Using a browser and the DNS name you discovered, attempt to load the web site on each server from the other server. Aka from VM_A, open a browser and go to http://VM_B

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work. Here's the error message seen from the browser: "The connection has timed out

The server at VM_B is taking too long to respond.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web." Note that I also double checked the server is running by visiting http://VM_B on VM_B and was able to observe that the webpage loaded.