# Azure VMs are not able to inter-communicate each other

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created few virtual machines with same `ResourceGroup` and `NetworkSecurityGroup`. I am not using custom DNS but default one.

Now, I want these machines to talk each other, can use shared folders of each others and so on.

For example: VM named `Machine-2` can access shared folder of another VM `Machine-1` like:  `\\\Machine-1\SharedFolder`

I have gone through some similar threads like below:

- [Azure VMs Virtual Network inter-communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995734/azure-vms-virtual-network-inter-communication)
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/

Right now, these VMs are even not ping-able from others.

Comment: Post this to ServerFault, not StackOverflow (it's not programming-related).

Answer (score -1):

You should look at [Azure Files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/). It exploits your existing storage account and it is very easy to use.

Comment: This wasn't a question about using SMB file shares like Azure Files. It was a question regarding sharing content between VMs, and communicating between VMs. At best, this should be a comment under the question. It's not an answer.

Comment: Hi David, sorry but I cannot sense the reason of your hostility. As I read this, the question seems to me that Anil wants a VM to access a folder of the other VM. If this is the only need then Azure Files is the way to do this and there is no reason to create some other connectivity between them.

Comment: No hostility at all. But it's not an answer. It's a product suggestion. A good one, but... it doesn't answer the core question. That's why it should be a comment.

Comment: Anyway sorry, but I did not have enough reputation to comment and with this attitude from StackOverflow members I do not think that you let new people come in thhe community. </offtopic>
Nevertheless, from what I get that Anil wants to do the Files solutions should work, and Anil If you need any help in that I shall be at your service.